# Connection Pool Doesn't reach it's max connection pool Hikari CP

Tags: database, spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp

sorry for my bad english.

[image: Hikari Connection Pooling]

From grafana montirong above, as you can see some state about connection pool in Hikari CP:

- **Pending threads** started from 25
- **Active connection** started from 10
- **Iddle threads** started from 0

From those states as you can see some threads are queueing to get connection from connection pool and some are active querying. The problem was the `maximum-pool-size=130`, i don't know why but according to active connection and iddle connection maybe i dont understood enough. I think active connection will be increased according to `maximum-pool-size` i was set before, but why it keeps only 10 connection open?

And it causes this error, which i cannot get connection in connection pool because all connection are actively used by other threads
[image: Error Hikari]

Comment: maximum is for the allowed max, the pool will scale down again to min-idle (which is 10 by default).